# Pandas python data not being stored when output to the excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-crawler, data-export

i am just trying to webcrawl a site and have the data exported to excel using pandas. The result is only printing the columns instead of the result despite .appending to data (list).. I've done quite alot of googling and finally came here seeking for advice... I have updated the previous question as it may not be sufficient according to the Minimal Viable Product? questioning requirement..

The summary of the code below is as below (Tourism site)

Hardcoded static variables
Go into website
Loop through all the prefectures
Find out how many Posts to Loop through
Gather URL Links
For loop Go into each Page and extract data and continuously append information into data=[]

export and print it to excel at the end..

that was my ideal plan.. it seems so close and yet so far...

```
import os
import sys
import time
import math
import urllib.request
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from Stamprally import StamprallyInfo
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


prefectureNameList = ["海外"]

# ,"北海道地方", "北海道", "東北地方", "青森県", "岩手県", "宮城県", "秋田県", "山形県", "福島県", "関東地方", "茨城県", "栃木県", "群馬県", "埼玉県", "千葉県", "東京都", "神奈川県", "中部地方", "新潟県", "富山県", "石川県", "福井県", "山梨県", "長野県", "岐阜県", "静岡県",
#                       "愛知県", "三重県", "近畿地方", "滋賀県", "京都府", "大阪府", "兵庫県", "奈良県", "和歌山県", "中国地方", "鳥取県", "島根県", "岡山県", "広島県", "山口県", "四国地方", "徳島県", "香川県", "愛媛県", "高知県", "九州・沖縄地方", "福岡県", "佐賀県", "長崎県", "熊本県", "大分県", "宮崎県", "鹿児島県", "沖縄県"]


data = []
contentAggregator = []
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Total List Number", "Prefecture", "ListLink", "Location Tag", "Event Tag", "Available Period",
                  "Available StartDate", "End Date", "Last Updated", "Main Image URL", "Title", "innerWebSiteURL", "mainText"])
main_url = 'https://stamprally.org/'
driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(main_url)

prefectureValueStorage = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='header_search_cat1']/option[2]").get_attribute('value')

# [x.get_attribute('value') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
#     "//select[@name='search_cat1']/option[@class='level-1' or @class='level-0']")]

prefectureNameIterator = -1
# Loop through all the different prefectures
# for prefectureValue in prefectureValueStorage:
start = time.time()
prefectureNameIterator += 1
driver.get(
    f"https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1={145}&search_cat2=0")

print("START OF PREFECTURE " + prefectureNameList[prefectureNameIterator])

# Calculate How Many Times To Run Page Loop
imageDownloadCounter = 1
totalList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    'div.page_navi2.clearfix>p').text  # .get_attribute('text')
totalListNum = totalList.split("件中")
# Add TotalListNum to the contentAggregator
contentAggregator.append(int(totalListNum[0]))
if int(totalListNum[0]) % 10 != 0:
    pageLoopCount = math.ceil((int(totalListNum[0])/10))
else:
    pageLoopCount = int(totalListNum[0])/10
# continue
currentpage = 0
while currentpage < pageLoopCount:
    currentpage += 1
    print("Current Page " + str(currentpage))

# ========================================================================================================================================================
# # Loop through all the Listings within the prefecture page
    driver.get(
        f"https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1={145}&search_cat2=0&paged={currentpage}")
    # print("Loading Page %s" % currentpage)
    # ========================================================================================================================================================
    # Add prefectureName to the contentAggregator
    # contentAggregator.append(prefectureNameList[prefectureNameIterator])
    # Gather All List Links
    urlList = []
    currentUrlCounter = 0
    listURLContainer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        '#post_list2 > li > a')
    # Put all the lists in one Array
    for url in listURLContainer:
        urlList.append(url.get_attribute('href'))
    # Loop through all the links
    for listURL in listURLContainer:
        contentAggregator = []
# Add TotalListNum to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(int(totalListNum[0]))
# Add prefectureName to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(
            prefectureNameList[prefectureNameIterator])
        print('article Link: ')
        print(urlList[currentUrlCounter])
    # Add listLink to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(
            urlList[currentUrlCounter])
    # for Each Links in listURLContainer:
        driver.get(urlList[currentUrlCounter])
        currentUrlCounter += 1
        locationTag = [x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='post_meta_top']/li[1]/a[@class='cat-category']")]
        print(locationTag)
    # Add locationTag to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(locationTag)

        eventTag = [x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='post_meta_top']/li[2]/a[@class='cat-category2']")]
        contentAggregator.append(eventTag)
        print(eventTag)
 
        availablePeriod = (driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'div#post_date')).text.split("（ ")
        availablePeriodFormatted = availablePeriod[0].replace("開催期間：", "")
        availableStartDate = availablePeriod[0].split(" ～ ")
        endDate = availableStartDate[1]
        availableStartDateFormatted = availableStartDate[0].replace(
            "開催期間：", "")
    # Select Latest Update Date
        lastUpdatedDate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'time.entry-date.updated').text
        print("Available Period:")
        print(availablePeriodFormatted)
    # Add Available Period to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(availablePeriodFormatted)
        print("Available StartDate:")
        print(availableStartDateFormatted)
    # Add Available StartDate to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(availableStartDateFormatted)
        print("End Date: ")
        print(endDate)
    # Add endDate to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(endDate)
        print("Last Updated:")
        print(lastUpdatedDate[6:])
    # Add lastUpdatedDate to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(lastUpdatedDate[6:])
# ========================================================================================================================================================
    # Download Main Post Image
        mainImageUrl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'img.attachment-post-thumbnail.size-post-thumbnail.wp-post-image').get_attribute('src')
    # Add lastUpdatedDate to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(mainImageUrl)
    # Save Post Main Title
        postTitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'h2#post_title').text.replace(" 開催終了", "")
        print("Title: ")
        print(postTitle)
    # Add Title to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(postTitle)
    # Save Post Main Image
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(mainImageUrl, (str(
            prefectureNameList[prefectureNameIterator])+postTitle+str(imageDownloadCounter) + ".png"))
        imageDownloadCounter += 1
    # Get Inner Website Link
        innerWebSiteButtonURL = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'div.post_content.clearfix > div >a').get_attribute('href')
        print("inner Website Button URL: " + innerWebSiteButtonURL)
    # Add innerWebSiteURL to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(innerWebSiteButtonURL)
    # Gather Main Post Text Content
        mainText = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            'div.post_content.clearfix > p')
        mainContentText = []
    # Remove Disclamimer text
        for mainContentDetail in mainText:
            mainContentText.append(mainContentDetail.text)
        mainContextTextCount = len(mainContentText)-1
        print(mainContentText[:mainContextTextCount])
    # Add Main Post Text Content to the contentAggregator
        contentAggregator.append(mainContentText[:mainContextTextCount])

    # ========================================================================================================================================================
            contentReorder = [1, 0, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 3, 4, 9, 11, 2]
            contentAggregator = [contentAggregator[i] for i in contentReorder]
            print("=====================================================================================================================================================")
            print(contentAggregator)
            data.append(contentAggregator)
            print(data)
            print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Total List Number", "Prefecture", "ListLink", "Location Tag", "Event Tag", "Available Period",
                                              "Available StartDate", "End Date", "Last Updated", "Main Image URL", "Title", "innerWebSiteURL", "mainText"]))
            end = time.time()
            print(end - start)


xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('StampRally_Crawler.xlsx')
df.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name="Stamprally.org Crawl Result")
xlwriter.close()
# ========================================================================================================================================================
# Close  Off
driver.close()
driver.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: where do you append your data to your dataframe?

Comment: @SpaceBurger intersting name.. hehe anyhow, i updated the post so it would be easier for ppl to diagnose. I hope this answers your question and thanks for the support much appreciated

Comment: you have initialised your df  in line `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Total List Number", "Prefecture", "ListLink", "Location Tag", "Event Tag", "Available Period",
                  "Available StartDate", "End Date", "Last Updated", "Main Image URL", "Title", "innerWebSiteURL", "mainText"])` , while in your loop you are printing the dataframe but you have not assigned that to your df. you could try to move the code line I pasted just before your end time calculation.

Comment: @simpleApp thank you so much, yes it works now :) I'm just alittle curious because i believe i did data.append(contentAggregator) to assign the appended information to an array of data... i also ran a debug during my troubleshoot and confirmed that the variable data contained the necessary information. Apologies for additional question and thanks again

Comment: you are welcome. you can think like this - i have df and feed with the data(empty at this time), now my df contain data(i.e all empty though). Then through program i added more content to data(data.append()), for sure data has more entries now; df will not know about this data as it was never assigned or visible to it. for further reading : There is concept called pooling(you can google it) where some program read the data source again and again, and refresh it. I hope this  will be little helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have initialized your df in line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Total List Number", "Prefecture", "ListLink", "Location Tag", "Event Tag", "Available Period",                   "Available StartDate", "End Date", "Last Updated", "Main Image URL", "Title", "innerWebSiteURL", "mainText"])
```

while in your loop you are printing the dataframe but you have not assigned that to your df. you could try to move the code line I pasted just before your end time calculation.